# Getting Error when Restoring SQL Database using VB.net

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, restore

> Error Message: Exclusive access could not be obtained because the
>   database is in use. restore database is terminating abnormally.

My Backup code works but I don't know why this restore code doesn't work.

```vb
Try
    Dim con2 As SqlConnection
    Dim com2 As SqlCommand
    Dim filename2 As String
    Dim strquery2 As String
    Dim database2 As String
    Dim get_servername2 As String

    'get the value selected in Database Name Dropdown Menu
    database2 = Database_NameComboBox.Text
    'get the value selected in Server Name Dropdown Menu
    get_servername2 = Server_NameComboBox.Text.Trim

    Dim opendlg As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim constr2 As String

    ' set SQL connection data source using default Master Database
    constr2 = "Data Source=" & get_servername2 & ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"

    ' open SQL Database to restore
    If opendlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        con2 = New SqlConnection(constr2)
        con2.Open()
        filename2 = opendlg.FileName
        strquery2 = "Restore database " & database2 & " from disk='" & filename2 & "'"

        ' execute command
        Try
            com2 = New SqlCommand(strquery2, con2)
            com2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Database " & database2 & " has been Restored Successfully", "IBP Legal Aid Case Management System - Restore Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            con2.Close()
            Me.Server_NameComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
            Me.Database_NameComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
            Me.Database_NameComboBox.Enabled = False
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: You could have another connection open. For example here in your catch block you don't close the connection. Look at how to use the _Using statement_ and change your code pattern everywhere in your program

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injection. Learn to properly parameterize your code - it does not matter if this app will only be used internally. Develop good habits.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to `restore` you should be sure there is no user connected to this `database`, otherwise you get the error you posted.

You can first set your db `offline` and then restore:

```
alter database MyDB set offline
with rollback immediate;

restore database ...
```